# How to update fields that are a string to an array with the string mongodb

Tags: mongodb

At some point data was saved as a string instead of an array of strings.  There are some records that now have a value of:

```
users: "someuser@gmail.com"
```

but it should be:

```
users: ["someuser@gmail.com"]
```

Is there a way to update this in MongoDB?

Something like is what is a start, but I don't want to lose the data in the field.  I need that info still, just inside an array:

```
db.users.update({users: {$type: 2}, {$set: {users: {$type: 4}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to modify existing collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            users: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ { $type: "$users" }, "string" ] }, [ "$users" ], "$users" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "collection"
    }
])
```

Comment: Note that this solution will turn fields that already contain an array into an array within an array

Comment: @Plancke you are absolutely right, modified my answer, thank you !

Comment: I think the updated answer might still do it for every record, I could be wrong but the $type operator on array fields matches any element inside the array. I don't have access to a mongo install to confirm this right now though. Could possibly do `{"$users.0": {$exists: false}}` to check if there's an element at index 0?

Comment: @Plancke please take a look here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mFxdneyWc1u

Comment: Ah, interesting, I recalled a few instances giving me troubles before using types with array, glad it works like this.

Comment: Thank you!  So awesome.